# How to modify a file with sed?

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, sed

I need to modify a file in a Docker image. I would like to change the line 2357 of a Python module `mod.py` with sed, how can I do that ?

```
        raise ExchangeError(self.id + ' ' + errorText + '(#' + errorCode + ')')
```

The desired output would be:

```
        raise ExchangeError(self.id + '(#' + errorCode + ')')
```

or

```
        raise ExchangeError(self.id)
```

Comment: `sed --in-place "s/        raise ExchangeError(self.id + ' ' + errorText + '(#' + errorCode + ')')/        raise ExchangeError(self.id + '(#' + errorCode + ')')/g" /path/to/python/file.py`

Comment: I didn't read carefully, I wasn't aware that the file is inside a docker, I have never used dockers so I don't know for sure whether Python will work. But my point still stands, that anything `sed` can do, Python can. And `sed` can't do anything Python can. Use string splitting and indexing then `re.sub`. As for the downvote, I didn't cast it. But now you have two downvotes. Your question isn't useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with:

```
sed -i "2357s/+ ' ' + errorText //" path/mod.py
```

Comment: Does this remove `+ ' ' + errorText ` ?

Comment: Yes, it substitutes "+ ' ' + errorText " for an empty string so deletes that part (and only on the target line number).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following sed command to replace content on a specific line:

```
sed '2357s/AAA/BBB/'
```

Where:

- 2357 is the target line number
- s stands for "substitute", meaning replace a string
- AAA is your original string, in your usecase:

> raise ExchangeError(self.id + ' ' + errorText + '(#' + errorCode +
> ')')

- BBB is the desired replacement string

You might have to play around with escaping special characters.

Answer (score 0):

If the line you want to edit is unique in the code, try the following.

`sed -i 's|raise ExchangeError(self.id + ' ' + errorText + '(#' + errorCode + ')') .*|raise ExchangeError(self.id + '(#' + errorCode + ')')|' mod.py`

It would search for the exact line and replace it.

The cleaner syntax is as follows:

```
sed -i 's|text_to_match .*|text_to_replace_with|' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '2357c\raise ExchangeError(self.id + '\''(#'\'' + errorCode + '\'')'\'')' file
```

or

```
sed -i '2357c\raise ExchangeError(self.id)' file
```